# iText 5.5.3 + XFAWorker: Repeated section not rendering

Tags: itext

We are using iText Java 5.5.3 with XFAWorker to inject XML into PDF templates and flatten those to simple PDFs.

To integrate into a system that has parts built in various technologies we have wrapped it into a http-Server using the [simple framework](http://www.simpleframework.org/)

The injection stage works fine, but after flattening some sections are lost.

Detailled information:

- The PDF template we inject into is: [CLAIM.Plan.pdf](http://qvwx.de/tmp/CLAIM.Plan.pdf).
- Sample data we try to inject is: [plan_v4.xml](http://qvwx.de/tmp/plan_v4.xml).
- Without flattening we get: [CLAIM_plan_unflattened.pdf](http://qvwx.de/tmp/CLAIM_plan_unflattened.pdf).
- With flattening the result is [CLAIM_plan_flattened.pdf](http://qvwx.de/tmp/CLAIM_plan_flattened.pdf).

[plan_v4.xml](http://qvwx.de/tmp/CLAIM_plan_flattened.pdf) has multiple instances of //form/PlanItems/PlanItem and [CLAIM_plan_v3.pdf][6] is repeating the section to display all of them. This is the OK case. [CLAIM_plan_v4.pdf][7] is not showing the repeated sections for the individual PlanItem instances. This is the broken case.

The main bit of code that uses iText looks like this:

```
// load the XML document that contains the contents of the data element.
// NOT the <data> element itself or anything else. 
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();              
Document newdoc = db.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(xfaStream, "UTF-8")));

Node newdata = newdoc.getDocumentElement();

// Open the PDF and extract the complete xfa.
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfStream);
XfaForm xfa = new XfaForm(reader);
Document doc = xfa.getDomDocument();

// Remove all contents of the <data> element
NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/", "data");

Node child;
do {
    child = list.item(0).getFirstChild();
    if (child!=null) {
        list.item(0).removeChild(child);
    }
} while (child!=null);

// Replace <data> with the new xml to inject.
list.item(0).appendChild(doc.importNode(newdata,true));

ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, os, '\0', false);

xfa.setDomDocument(doc);

xfa.setChanged(true);
XfaForm.setXfa(xfa, stamper.getReader(), stamper.getWriter());
stamper.close();
```

If I now just finish quickly:

```
response.getOutputStream().write(os.toByteArray());
```

I get the good (but unflattened) result.

If I add the flattening stage like this:

```
com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
XFAFlattener xfaf = new XFAFlattener(document, writer);
xfaf.flatten(new PdfReader(os.toByteArray()));
document.close();
```

The result is flattened but missing the repeated sections.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong so the PlanItems don't get rendered in the final PDF?

Comment: Hi Marian, as far as I understand this issues already has been reported to iText support as a separate ticket. Right? We're working on it right now. Please follow our progress on iText ticketing system.

Comment: Hi Marian. The reported issue is resolved. More details are in our ticketing system

Comment: Used the 5.5.4-SNAPSHOT libraries provided and verified the issue is resolved.